# ng-repeat within tabs not working, showing same content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS and facing this issue.

Scenario:

I have an array of photos in below object

```
{{place.result.photos}}
```

I am applying ng-repeat on "Photos" TAB.

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <p>Address: {{ place.result.formattedAddress }}</p>
  <p>
    Average Rating: 4.5 | 
    <a href="#reviews" data-toggle="modal">Read all reviews</a>    
  </p>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Photos</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Info</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="home" >
      <p>
        <div ng-repeat="(index, photo) in place.result.photos">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference={{photo.reference}}&sensor=true&key=3S3JKeT6L0dDkosHoSyevaY"/>
            <br ng-show="(index+1)%4==0"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="profile">
      <p>{{ place.result.formattedAddress }}</p>
      <p>{{ place.result.formattedPhoneNumber}}</p>
      <p>{{ place.result.website }}</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**ISSUE**

For the first tab, its working fine. but rest of the ng-repeat elements, when clicked, only first element tab gets updated and in other array repeat elements, nothing works.

What could be the issue? Please help! TIA!

Comment: could you give a fiddle?

Comment: And: what is the structure of `place.result.photos`?

Comment: Yes, fiddle is needed. Its hard to understand the question!

Answer (score 0):

Check out $index in [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

The code is:

```
<div ng-repeat="photo in place.result.photos">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference={{photo.reference}}&sensor=true&key=3S3JKeT6L0dDkosHoSyevaY"/>
    <br ng-show="($index+1)%4==0"/>
  </div>
</div>
```